# Why is Xubuntu 22.04 unable to boot from USB?

Tags: boot, system-installation, xubuntu, lubuntu

I have laptop with Intel Core i3-380M processor and 4GB RAM. But, when I going attempt to install newest version of Xubuntu today and another Ubuntu flavours, version 22.04, my computer after just only only displays a small dash in the upper left corner and immediately hangs or crash. I believe that no corrupt in ISO file on flashdrive. Oddly enough, Ubuntu 22.04 can be installed without any problem as mentioned before.

So, what happen to my computer?. To my knowledge, Xubuntu is a one of lightweight Ubuntu derivative alongside with Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, etc.

```
---------- General Computer Specifications:

  --- Computer/CPU Information from 'lshw -C cpu' --- 
*-Cpu
    Description: CPU
    Product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 380  @ 2.53GHz
    Vendor: Intel Corp.
    Physical id: 29
    Bus info: cpu@0
    Version: 6.37.5
    Slot: CPU
    Size: 971MHz
    Capacity: 2533MHz
    Width: 64 bits
    Clock: 1066MHz
    Capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 
        apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse 
        sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs 
        bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 
        monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 
        popcnt lahf_lm pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority 
        ept vpid dtherm arat flush_l1d cpufreq
    Configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 microcode=7 threads=4

badrchannels
    Description: Notebook
    Product: Aspire 4738Z (Calpella_CRB)
    Vendor: Acer
    Version: V1.02
    Serial: LXR7H0C00103318A242500
    Width: 64 bits
    Capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
    Configuration:
        boot=normal
        chassis=notebook
        family=Intel_Mobile
        sku=Calpella_CRB
        uuid=b26e6fe3-226e-324f-af99-60eb691f455e

------------------ SMBIOS Information from '/sys/class/dmi/id/' 
Bios Vendor:         INSYDE
Bios Version:        V1.02
Bios Release:        2.240
Board Vendor:        Acer
Board Name:          ZQ8
Board Version:       Base Board Version
Board Serial:        033AA6MBQTF007C0
Board Asset Tag:     Base Board Asset Tag

Current boot mode:   Legacy mode (alias CSM alias BIOS mode)
   --- SecureBoot Status from 'mokutil':
EFI variables are not supported on this system

---------- Memory Information:
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.5Gi       1.2Gi       106Mi        88Mi       2.3Gi       2.0Gi
Swap:           16Gi       2.0Mi        16Gi

---------- IP Address Information:
  --- IP Address Information from 'ip addr' --- 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
2: enp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.1.7/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
    inet6 fe80::b384:26ae:5153:2465/64 scope link noprefixroute 

  --- Internet Connection Status from 'ping [various addresses]' --- 
Connected to Internet with DNS

  --- Network Device Status Summary from 'ip addr' ---  
These Network Devices are up:
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000

  --- Hostname from 'hostname --fqdn' ---  
The 'Hostname' of the computer system is: badrchannels

---------- Storage Controller Information From 'lspci':
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller
        Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
        Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
        Latency: 0
        Interrupt: pin B routed to IRQ 24
        Region 0: I/O ports at 3048 [size=8]
        Region 1: I/O ports at 305c [size=4]
        Region 2: I/O ports at 3040 [size=8]
        Region 3: I/O ports at 3058 [size=4]
        Region 4: I/O ports at 3020 [size=32]
        Region 5: Memory at d4405000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
                Address: fee02004  Data: 0025
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
                Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
                Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0 BAR4 Offset=00000004
        Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
                AFCap: TP+ FLR+
                AFCtrl: FLR-
                AFStatus: TP-
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

---------- File system specs from 'df -h':
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3      ext4  292G   26G  252G  10% /
/dev/sda2      vfat  512M  5.3M  507M   2% /boot/efi

---------- Disk/Partition Information From 'fdisk':

Disk /dev/sda: 298.09 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Disk model: Hitachi HTS54503
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A11111A8-174B-4FEC-8317-BBB88EB05FAF

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048     1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   1054719   1050624   513M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1054720 625141759 624087040 297.6G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/sdc: 7.55 GiB, 8110768128 bytes, 15841344 sectors
Disk model: USB Flash Disk  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x66c6e244

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 15837183 15835136  7.6G  b W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sdb: 14.54 GiB, 15615393792 bytes, 30498816 sectors
Disk model: Card  Reader    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

---------- Disk/Partition Information From 'lsblk':
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE   LABEL MOUNTPOINT                         MODEL
sda    298.1G                                                   Hitachi HTS545032B9A300
|-sda1     1M                                                   
|-sda2   513M vfat           /boot/efi                          
`-sda3 297.6G ext4           /                                  
sdb     14.5G swap           [SWAP]                             Card Reader
sdc      7.6G                                                   USB Flash Disk
`-sdc1   7.6G vfat     SLAX                                     
sr0     1024M                                                   PIONEER DVD-RW DVRTD11RS
   ------- 'lsblk' information continued ...
NAME   HOTPLUG PARTUUID                             UUID
sda          0                                      
|-sda1       0 5209958e-dc00-4fb8-9140-116f0c0ec35d 
|-sda2       0 a869850d-33ef-4813-9eab-c86e7f89af6b 9390-A138
`-sda3       0 cbb475d8-e686-490f-9d44-1962a64e7d13 142ee8b0-27aa-4566-8824-7def52cfebcd
sdb          1                                      26965438-0d20-4c61-9274-ffb9c54bf553
sdc          1                                      
`-sdc1       1 66c6e244-01                          48E4-1606
sr0          1                                      

---------- Mount Details of '/etc/fstab':
UUID=142ee8b0-27aa-4566-8824-7def52cfebcd /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=9390-A138  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Multiple_Card_Reader_058F63666433-0:0 none swap sw 0 0

---------- Current Mount Details of 'mount':
/dev/sda2 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)

---------- USB Information from 'lsusb -t -v':
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
            ID 0402:9665 ALi Corp. Gateway Webcam
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
            ID 0402:9665 ALi Corp. Gateway Webcam
        |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            ID 24a9:1302  
        |__ Port 5: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader

---------- Video Details from 'lshw':

  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1366,768
       resources: 
           irq:25 
           memory:d0000000-d03fffff 
           memory:c0000000-cfffffff 
           ioport:3050(size=8) 
           memory:c0000-dffff

   --- Graphics Environment Continued from 'various graphics ENVs' ----
The Current Configured Destop is: XFCE 
The Current Desktop Session is: xfce 
The Current X Desktop Information Details from 'xrandr' are: 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
The Current Session Type is: x11 
The Current Display Manager is: lightdm
The Current Desktop Theme: 'Fluent'
The Current Virtual TTY's being used are:
        TTY#    Used By
        tty1    agetty
        tty7    Xorg
        pts/0   bash
        pts/0   system-info
        pts/0   system-info
        pts/0   less
        pts/0   system-info
        pts/0   ps
        pts/0   awk

---------- Repository Information from '/etc/apt/sources.list and etc/apt/sources.list.d/':

Sources List:
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse

Sources List from SourcesD:
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary-os-ubuntu-daily-jammy.list:
File had no entries.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-core-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list:
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/agornostal-ubuntu-ulauncher-jammy.list:
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/agornostal/ulauncher/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/elementary-os-ubuntu-daily-jammy.list.save:
File had no entries.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list:
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:
deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/inkscape_dev-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list.save:
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/agornostal-ubuntu-ulauncher-jammy.list.save:
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/agornostal/ulauncher/ubuntu/ jammy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kelebek333-ubuntu-mint-tools-jammy.list:
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/kelebek333/mint-tools/ubuntu/ jammy main

---------- Other Details from 'Various':
The current kernel version is:       5.15.0-40-generic 
The current release description is:  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS 
Original Installation Date:          2022-06-24+17:49:06 
Original Installation Media: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS "Jammy Jellyfish" - Release amd64 (20220419)
Do-Release-Upgrade Date: This system may have not had a 'Release Upgrade' through 'do-release-upgrade'

These are the current kernel ranges for HWE kernels for this release.
   --- HWE Kernel Reference from 'apt-cache show':
For HWE Package: linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04, Kernel Version: 5.15.0.40.42
For HWE Package: linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04, Kernel Version: 5.15.0.39.40
For HWE Package: linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04, Kernel Version: 5.15.0.25.27

   --- HWE Package Status from 'dpkg':
Package linux-generic-hwe-22.04 is installed.

   --- Certified Hardware Platform Status: (By the Ubuntu Wiki Standards)
Ubuntu Certified Hardware Platform. Safe to install 
the Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE).

   --- User Installed Package List:
adwaita-icon-theme-full
code
contractor
default-jre
doc-base
fcitx5
fcitx5-chewing
fcitx5-chinese-addons
fcitx5-frontend-gtk2
fcitx5-frontend-gtk3
fcitx5-frontend-gtk4
fcitx5-frontend-qt5
fcitx5-module-cloudpinyin
font-manager
gdebi
git
gnome-clocks
gnome-software
gnome-tweaks
google-chrome-stable
gtk3-im-libthai
hunspell-bg
hunspell-ca
hunspell-cs
hunspell-da
hunspell-hu
hunspell-nl
hunspell-no
hunspell-pl
hunspell-sv
hunspell-sv-se
hunspell-th
hunspell-tr
hunspell-uk
hunspell-vi
hyphen-bg
hyphen-ca
hyphen-cs
hyphen-da
hyphen-de
hyphen-en-ca
hyphen-en-gb
hyphen-en-us
hyphen-es
hyphen-fr
hyphen-hu
hyphen-it
hyphen-nl
hyphen-no
hyphen-pl
hyphen-pt-br
hyphen-pt-pt
hyphen-ru
hyphen-sv
hyphen-uk
inkscape
io.elementary.notifications
io.elementary.terminal
kde-config-fcitx5
kdenlive
libfuse2
libgstreamer0.10-0
librsvg2-bin
lightdm
lightdm-gtk-greeter
lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings
meson
minbar
minbar-data
multiarch-support
mythes-bg
mythes-ca
mythes-cs
mythes-da
mythes-de
mythes-de-ch
mythes-en-au
mythes-en-us
mythes-es
mythes-fr
mythes-hu
mythes-it
mythes-no
mythes-pt-pt
mythes-ru
mythes-sv
mythes-uk
ntp
ntpdate
numlockx
onboard
openjdk-8-jre
openjfx
plank
ppa-purge
python-is-python3
python3-distutils-extra
stellarium
task-xfce-desktop
tasksel
thunderbird-locale-bg
thunderbird-locale-ca
thunderbird-locale-cs
thunderbird-locale-da
thunderbird-locale-de
thunderbird-locale-en
thunderbird-locale-en-gb
thunderbird-locale-en-us
thunderbird-locale-es
thunderbird-locale-es-ar
thunderbird-locale-es-es
thunderbird-locale-fr
thunderbird-locale-hu
thunderbird-locale-it
thunderbird-locale-ja
thunderbird-locale-nb
thunderbird-locale-nb-no
thunderbird-locale-nl
thunderbird-locale-pl
thunderbird-locale-pt
thunderbird-locale-pt-br
thunderbird-locale-pt-pt
thunderbird-locale-ru
thunderbird-locale-sv
thunderbird-locale-sv-se
thunderbird-locale-th
thunderbird-locale-tr
thunderbird-locale-uk
thunderbird-locale-vi
thunderbird-locale-zh-cn
thunderbird-locale-zh-hans
thunderbird-locale-zh-hant
thunderbird-locale-zh-tw
tor
touchegg
ulauncher
unity-greeter
vlc
warpinator
xfce4-notifyd
xfce4-panel-profiles
xfce4-session
xfce4-settings
xfdesktop4
xfwm4
xterm

Currently logged in User(s):
NAME     LINE         TIME         COMMENT
muhammadikamz tty7         Jul  2 08:42 (:0)

The User running this script was: muhammadikamz
uid=1000(muhammadikamz)
gid=1000(muhammadikamz)
groups=1000(muhammadikamz),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),
122(lpadmin),134(lxd),135(sambashare)

The 'system-info' script was booted from an installed system.

The 'system-info' script was run locally on the system

The Linux Kernel Command Line use to boot was: 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-40-generic root=UUID=142ee8b0-27aa-4566-8824-7def52cfebcd ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

*** End Of Report ***
```

This is my system report as requested by [sudodus](https://askubuntu.com/users/55537/sudodus) yesterday in comment

Comment: I would verify the ISO as being valid; and then ensure the media verification was successful; using another machine if necessary. I'm involved with QA-testing; and if I was in your positioned I'd bet odds on a bad ISO write to your *flash* media assuming you validated the ISO after downloading... Lubuntu/Xubuntu and all *flavor* ISOs are created by the same procedure as main Ubuntu; so I'd expect the to boot the same (Lubuntu doesn't include OEM so some differences do exist; but you've provided no graphics details that would allow validation on differences there...)

Comment: You can help us help you by giving us more information about your computer. One way to do that is to, when booted into a version and flavour of Ubuntu that works (live from USB or installed) download and run the [Ubuntu Forum's  `system-info` script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/), let it upload the results to a pastebin and post a link to the pastebin.

Comment: Thanks for the output from the system-info script. (But why did you put the result into the original question instead of letting it upload the result to a pastebin and put a link to the pastebin into the original question?) Anyway, I notice that standard Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS works, and I see nothing that should make it impossible to run Xubuntu.

Comment: I agree with you, normally Xubuntu should work well in old computers, better than standard Ubuntu. There must be some very special feature (or maybe a temporary hiccup) that caused Xubuntu to fail. **I suggest some trial and error now with Lubuntu or Ubuntu MATE**, also light-weight flavours of Ubuntu with good chances to work well. They can work faster than standard Ubuntu and use less RAM for the 'basics' leaving more RAM available for the application programs. And last but not least, they they come with some lightweight application programs (replacing heavier tools of standard Ubuntu).

Comment: https://termbin.com/26b7
This is mine

Comment: Now you can actually remove the output code from your original question. Next I am looking forward to your decision about trial and error now with Lubuntu or Ubuntu MATE. Are you happy enough with Ubuntu as it is installed now, or will you try those lightweight community flavours? Anyway, please share your thoughts :-)

Comment: Okay, insha Allah

Comment: I was tried, and the results are failed. Lubuntu and Ubuntu MATE can't enter installation enviroment. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-onnQmle7Lf7NtcSxCrOQ3jN72IMIQJ6/view?usp=drivesdk. This is my video when I tried to boot Ubuntu MATE from USB

Comment: Strangely enough, Ubuntu installation is run normally

Comment: The video only shows ~13 secs of black-screen; so isn't conclusive as we don't know how long Ubuntu Desktop took in that situation (there are boxes with *firmware* where >10 minutes are required; maybe you walked out of the room & didn't realize how long Ubuntu Desktop had to boot from *live* media).  Your prior termbin showed as I read it, a *generic* kernel, not OEM kernel so I'd expect the same for all *flavors* to main Ubuntu Desktop (*given time required to boot of course*).

Comment: What's mean?. All of Ubuntu flavours is can't be installed, except it's Ubuntu itself in my laptop.

Comment: You may not have been as *patient* with Ubuntu *flavors* as you were with Ubuntu Desktop in booting *live* media.. Ubuntu *flavors* and Ubuntu Desktop boot the same way from *live* media and can require >10 minutes to boot; your boxes *firmware* control this.  if you boot Ubuntu Desktop & wait ~13 secs as per that video; I'd expect the same as I saw there with Ubuntu-MATE, or in fact Lubuntu/Xubuntu; ie. you may not have waited long enough (I leave boxes ~60 mins in QA before I explore why; as 9-12 mins occurs due to *outdated firmware*... This only impacts *live* media, not installed systems

Comment: My laptop after displaying small dash, the fan going to "whoosh, whoosh" and hangs.

Comment: All you can do is tell it to boot to runlevel 1 (at `grub`) and explore for issues... If it's a kernel hang etc, even SysRq commands won't work; but all of Xubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Lubuntu-Ubuntu Desktop all have the same base; so assuming no OEM kernel is selected via Ubuntu Desktop ISO & used instead (*and I didn't see one*) the writing of ISO to media is what I'd still blame as the all run the same Ubuntu code at boot; built by the same launchpad process...  (*differences are in the GUI which is run after boot of the same base Ubuntu system all use*)

Comment: I didn't see it "hung"...

At the Grub2 Boot Menu: Press the <E> key to get into the Edit mode of the menu option "try or install". <Arrow_down" until you get the the line that starts with the word "linux" (in lowercase). Then <Arrow-Right> on that line until you get to the words "quiet splash"... remove those two words, then add these words (without the quotation marks) "nomodeset verbose debug drm.debug=0xe plymouth:debug"
Then press <Cntrl><X> to boot that menu option. That should show us what is going on under the covers... Waiting to see the video of the boot process from there.

Comment: Sorry, but I will try with LMDE instead

Comment: if you want older software, you could also try an older Ubuntu stack as well.   As LMDE takes from *stable* and not *sid* (where Ubuntu does), you're starting from a much older stack; the DE my Ubuntu has is many versions newer than Debian *stable* currently has (Debian has the equivalent of Ubuntu 21.04 for my DE).  You're most welcome to use whatever software stack you wish; but be aware older releases of Ubuntu are available.